# how to print the sum of each row of a csv file in python

Tags: python, file, csv, sum

I opened the csv file and printed the rows and columns with this code

```
import pandas as pd
hw1_data = "C:/Users/Conor/Documents/hw1.csv"
hw1 = pd.read_csv(hw1_data)
print(hw1)
```

I just don't know how to sum each row of the file and print them on a seperate line.

Comment: `print(hw1.sum(axis=1))`. But make sure that all the values are numeric.

Answer (score 2):

I probably wouldn't even use `pandas` for this.

```
import csv

hw1_data = "C:/Users/Conor/Documents/hw1.csv"
with open(hw1_data) as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for l in r:
        print(sum(map(int, l)))
```

This will just print them to the standard output.  If you want them to a file that's fairly simple to do too.